# C directory traversal - printing directory names it shouldn't be

Tags: c

This is probably just a syntax thing that I'm doing wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure it out, so I apologize if this is too "HEY DEBUG MY CODE FOR ME!"

Relevant code:

```
struct dirent *readDir;
DIR *dir;
dir = opendir(name);

if(dir == NULL) {
    printf("No directory found with the name %s\n", name);
} else {
    printf("directory named %s opened.\n", name);

    while((readDir = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if(readDir->d_name != ".." || readDir->d_name != ".") {
            printf("%s\n", readDir->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

The if condition in the while loop doesn't seem to work, here's the output it produces:

```
directory named test opened.
file2
.
test2
file1
..
```

If I'm not mistaking, the if statement should filter out the . and .. directories, but it doesn't.  The goal of this is to be a recursive directory traversal, but unless I can keep it from recursing into the . and .. directories I can't really move on.

Basically, I don't know how to do string comparing I guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not support '!=' or '==' for string comparison. Use `strcmp`();

```
if(readDir->d_name != ".." || readDir->d_name != ".") {
```

Should be

```
if(strcmp(readDir->d_name, "..") && strcmp(readDir->d_name, ".")) {
    // d_name is not "." or ".."
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to C if it wasn't obvious.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the following:

```
if(readDir->d_name != ".." || readDir->d_name != ".") {
```

First, you cannot compare strings this way in C... you're essentially checking whether the address of the string literal matches the address in `readDir->d_name`.  You need to use a function like `strcmp()` instead.

Second, when you OR the conditions like that, only one needs to be true to make the whole expression true... and since `d_name` can't equal ".." AND "." simultaneously, the overall expression would always be TRUE even if the string comparisons *did* work as you (probably) expected.

So you need something like:

```
if (strcmp("..", readDir->d_name) && strcmp(".", readDir->d_name)) {
```

(since `strcmp()` returns non-zero when the strings *don't* match, and you need to *not* match both strings).

Comment: Yeah, I just caught the || problem.  Thanks for pointing it out though, it was more than I asked for lol.